# WSO2 ESB Using AuthenticationAdmin

Tags: wsdl, wso2, esb

I have a NetBeans Project and tried to creat an Web Service client with the following WSDL from WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 like in this [example](http://isharaaruna.blogspot.de/2012/06/how-to-consume-admin-service-in-wso2.html):

```
https://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl
```

But when NetBeans tries to create the client I get an error:
[image: NetBeans Error adding Web Service Client]

Why is this happening? I created other Web Service Clients, they are working, but this isn't working and I don't know why...

If I try it with eclipse I also get an error:

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing <soap:fault> element inFault "AuthenticationAdminAuthenticationException" in operation "AuthenticationAdminAuthenticationException", in binding logout
    java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing <soap:fault> element inFault "AuthenticationAdminAuthenticationException" in operation "AuthenticationAdminAuthenticationException", in binding logout
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.faultsFromSOAPFault(SymbolTable.java:2858)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populateBindings(SymbolTable.java:2549)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:744)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.add(SymbolTable.java:543)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:518)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Maybe the WSDL has an error?

Answer (score 1):

The [AuthenticationAdmin WSDL](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.1.0/service-stubs/org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub/4.1.0/src/main/resources/AuthenticationAdmin.wsdl) file is correct.

The logout operation is defined as a "[One-way](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_one-way)" operation. If you look at [AuthenticationAdmin.java](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.1.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.core.services/4.1.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/services/authentication/AuthenticationAdmin.java) implementation, you can see logout method has following signature.

`public void logout() throws AuthenticationException`

Note that the return type is "**void**", which means there is no output.

WSO2 uses Apache **Axis2** and there are no problems generating the client with Axis2.

I just tried creating a client with Eclipse & Apache Axis2. I could successfully create the stub.

WSO2 also uses the Service Stub created using [AuthenticationAdmin WSDL](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.1.0/service-stubs/org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub/4.1.0/src/main/resources/AuthenticationAdmin.wsdl). See `pom.xml` for more information about generating the client.

```
<java classname="org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java" fork="true">
    <arg line="-uri src/main/resources/AuthenticationAdmin.wsdl
    -u -uw -o target/generated-code
    -ns2p http://common.core.carbon.wso2.org/xsd=org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.authentication,http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org=org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub,http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org/xsd=org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub"/>
    <classpath refid="wsdl2java.classpath"/>
</java>
```

I'm getting the same error as you have shown, when I try to generate the client using Apache Axis. Therefore please make sure to use **Apache Axis2** as the web service runtime. Also make sure you point Axis2 directory in Eclipse `Preferences -> Web Services -> Axis2 Preferences`.

I also see NetBeans try to use wsimport utility. May be it doesn't support one-way operations properly.

I recommend you to use Apache Axis2 to generate the client.